# Svn checkout, checkin url

Tags: linux, svn

first, i am a complete newb when it comes to svn. i host my site on hostmonster and they dont official supoort svn but they dont really stop you from doing it. so i tried to set up my svn myself. so far it's going fine. i follow instruction [here](http://artis.imag.fr/~Xavier.Decoret/resources/svn/index.html). and i created and checked out a project via ssh. but how do i do a checkout via an IDE. the ide i am using is netbean. i guess there is a svn url that allows netbean to access my repository but i dont know what it is. and my repository is not under public_html.

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify, if you want Subversion to work via web URL (i.e. over http/https) you would also need to set up Apache with the dav_svn module and update your config files.

[However that shouldn't be necessary with Netbean](http://www.netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/subversion.html#checking), just use "svn+ssh://hostname/repository_path"

Answer (score 1):

This is probability a better question for stackoverflow.com.

Give this a go.

http://wiki.netbeans.org/TutorialUsingSVNLocalRepository